# SQL Server Replication Snapshot Error - Exception Message: An invalid option was specified for the statement "CREATE/ALTER FUNCTION"

Tags: sql-server, replication

The replication process was working fine. But when I added Views, UDF and Stored Procedures to replication process it throws this error.

> The replication agent had encountered an exception.
> Source: Replication
> Exception Type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.ReplicationAgentSqlException
> Exception Message: An invalid option was specified for the statement "CREATE/ALTER FUNCTION".
> A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.
> Message Code: 487

I am on SQL Server 2019 15.0.4355.3

I updated the SQL Server 2019 version to the most current for 2019.
I tried re-creating the subscriber.

Comment: are you sure you're on latest version on correct server? There's usually publisher and subscriber involved. cause your problem looks suspiciously like https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/kb4580949-fix-snapshot-agent-fails-when-you-create-transactional-publication-with-all-tables-and-udfs-in-sql-server-2019-41d0175d-88fb-ed87-e347-2f40faea9591

Comment: I ran the SQL Updates in both environments. Now I am getting "The option "INLINE=ON" is not valid for this function" and this has to do with UDF's.

Comment: Can it be you have different compatibility level on the servers?

Comment: I have made the combability the same at 150 for both environments. Now the subscription server just blanked all the data. The Data, Stored Procedures and Views. The  Replication monitor says that it is running with no Issues. I am a bit confused now